# How can I modify this working Javascript to allow the use of a simpler XML file?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have some Javascript which pulls some values from an XML file to graph it.  The code works fine, but the XML file has a lot of unnecessary data.  Here is the current (overly detailed) XML file contents:

```
<chart>
    <miles>
        <name>Car</name>
        <data>
            <distance>24</distance>
        </data>
        <name>Bike</name>
        <data>
            <distance>532</distance>
        </data>
    </miles>
</chart>
```

I'd like to simplify the XML file down to the following, but I'm not sure what to take out from my javascript below to read this reduced XML file:

```
<miles>
    <car>24</car>
    <bike>532</bike>
</miles>
```

Here is my javascript that reads the XML file and graphs the data using Highcharts.  How do I simplify this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            },
            series: []
        };

        // Load the data from the XML file 
        $.get('data.xml', function(xml) {

            // Split the lines
            var $xml = $(xml);

            // push series
            $xml.find('miles').each(function(i, series) {
                var seriesOptions = {
                    name: $(series).find('name').text(),
                    data: []
                };

                // push data points
                $(series).find('data distance').each(function(i, point) {
                    seriesOptions.data.push(
                        parseInt($(point).text())
                    );
                });

                // add it to the options
                options.series.push(seriesOptions);
            });
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

Comment: are you saying that in the "new format", you'll only have one `car` and one `bike` element for example?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The XML file is just an easy way to store the data for later processing.  No new elements are going to be added.

Comment: right, what is the expected result in `options.series`

Comment: It updates the options for the Highchart graphing.

Comment: yes, but what is the expected content of `options.series` I ask, because `data` seems to be an array with one element

Comment: regardless, https://jsfiddle.net/vmb9vm4u/ may help (note the complete lack of jquery :p )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I'm just trying to make my current javascript read the shorter XML file, not create a new XML file.

Comment: Oh right. So. Did you bother to look at the fiddle - I never even offered how to make a new XML file, ever, so not sure what you're reading

Comment: Yes, I did.  I saw what appeared to be a way to reduce information in an XML file, which is not what I was looking to solve.  You had multiple instances of car and bike in the XML file, and the file I'm working with will not have that.  I appreciate the help, it is just my lack of understanding that is the problem.

Comment: I wrote the code before you answered that. It works with 1 of each and should produce the correct results. Did you even look at the fiddle results

Comment: No, I couldn't get the fiddle to output anything.

Comment: it outputs `{"series":[{"name":"car","data":[24,26]},{"name":"bike","data":[532,52]}]}` ... if you remove the dupes, it would be `{"series":[{"name":"car","data":[24]},{"name":"bike","data":[532]}]}` - does your browser have developer tools console?

Comment: Ah, yes!  Now I see it.  I wasn't expecting the output in the developer's console.  Now I just need to study it to see what it would replace in my original code.  Looks like progress!